# CakePHP 3: How to properly check if a user is logged in

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 3, I found two ways to find if a user is logged in.

**1st solution**

```
if(!is_null($this->Auth->user('id'))){
        // Logged in
}
```

**2nd solution**

```
if (!is_null($this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id'))) {
    // Logged in
}
```

I think the first one is better because it's short and concise.

**Is there a better way to verify if a user is logged in?**

I'm not looking for speed necessarily. I want a clean and expressive way to write it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the best way is just:

```
if ($this->Auth->user()) {...}
```

Comment: I tried it with `$this->Auth->isAuthorized()` at first but that only worked for the home page. With `user()` it works. Weird.

Comment: But this is giving `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function user() on boolean `. I'm using this code in `AppController`

Comment: So you must have something wrong with AuthComponent. Maybe it's not loaded correctly or is override by something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using **`session()`** helper.

```
$loggeduser = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');
if(!$loggeduser) {
    $userID = $loggeduser['id'];
    $firstName = $loggeduser['first_name'];
}
```

Comment: Prior to 3.6.0 need to use getRequest() and getSession() so that it would be, `$loggeduser = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->read('Auth.User');`

Answer (score 0):

In my applications, I always use a login method like this:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error('Your username/password is not valid');
    }elseif ($this->Auth->user()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
    }
}
```

With this, if a user is logged ( **$this->Auth->user()** ) and the request is not a POST one, I redirect to a default URL.